# IP for aws same as Digital Ocean

Tags: amazon-web-services, digital-ocean

I am with digital Ocean but we r planning to move to AWS, can i get same IP which is with Digital Ocean. we will deploy new server on AWS instead of migrating from Digital ocean.
And If i will migrate from Digital ocean, will ip will be same or it will change

Comment: This is not a programming question and thus is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bring your own IP to AWS , read [this announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/announcing-bring-your-own-ip-for-amazon-virtual-private-cloud-preview/) but I highly doubt that Digital Ocean will release that IP to you , as it is IP owned by Digital Ocean.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey kush, 
Thanks to helping me. I need some more detail about this.

Comment: Please tell me what more do you want to know ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a domain name instead of IP , you can point/route it to AWS elastic IP associated to a instance.